# Image cropping in c#: values does not fall in expected range

Tags: c#, image

I found a cropping of image here at stackoverflow. It works if you select a small part of the image to crop.

Something like this.

[image]
 But when you select the whole picture. It gives an error.

Something like this.

[image]

Here is the link where I found the question and I just copied the source code

[Crop Image using Canvas Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240261/crop-image-using-canvas-rectangle)

and here is the error

```
    An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

pointing to this code (the one with the asterisk)

```
Rect rect1 = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(selectionRectangle), Canvas.GetTop(selectionRectangle), selectionRectangle.Width, selectionRectangle.Height);
                System.Windows.Int32Rect rcFrom = new System.Windows.Int32Rect();
                rcFrom.X = (int)((rect1.X) * (image1.Source.Width) / (image1.Width));
                rcFrom.Y = (int)((rect1.Y) * (image1.Source.Height) / (image1.Height));
                rcFrom.Width = (int)((rect1.Width) * (image1.Source.Width) / (image1.Width));
                rcFrom.Height = (int)((rect1.Height) * (image1.Source.Height) / (image1.Height));
                **BitmapSource bs = new CroppedBitmap(image1.Source as BitmapSource, rcFrom);**
                image2.Source = bs;
```

additional screenshot about the error
[image]

Comment: Well what is the value of rcFrom when it throws? (Also, maybe it is just the screenshots, but the examples look wrong..)

Comment: i updated the question sir. with additional screenshot of the error. i can upload the project if you want. thank you

Comment: Accoding to the [source for CroppedBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602486%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) it throws when the source is null, which would mean that image1.Source is not really of type BitmapSource. I could imagine that the rectangle also must fit in the source. You can test both in the debugger..